# Getting the matrix from system of equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to figure out how to get the matrix from a system of equations, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I understand how to represent equations such as \begin{equation*} a1 = 2x + 3y -5z\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}a2 =4x-2y+z\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}a3 = x-3y+4z\end{equation*} becoming \begin{bmatrix}2,3,-5\\4,-2,1\\1,-3,4\\\end{bmatrix}
however I've been looking at simpler examples of what I want (where there are not always the same values in each equation, and often there are extra variables included.

I've come across this example, and I'm wondering if there's a typo?\begin{equation*}dx/dt = ax-bxy\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}dy/dt = cxy-dy\end{equation*} becomes\begin{equation*}\begin{bmatrix}a-by, -bx\\cy, cx-d\end{bmatrix}\end{equation*}.

I presumed that in this example,\begin{equation*} a_{11} = \text{first equation with no x,}\end{equation*} \begin{equation*} a_{12} = \text{first equation with no y,}\end{equation*} \begin{equation*} a_{21} = \text{second equation with no x,}\end{equation*} \begin{equation*} a_{22} = \text{second equation with no y,}\end{equation*}

but that would make it\begin{equation*}\begin{bmatrix}a-by, ax-bx\\cy, cx-d\end{bmatrix}\end{equation*}.

For clarification, the type of equations I'll actually be dealing with are as so:
\begin{equation*} a1 = -a1*(a2*{c/N})\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}a2 =a1*(a2*{c/N})-a2*r\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}a3 = a2*r\end{equation*}.

where $c$ and $r$ are variables with different values, and $N$ is the sum of $a1,a2,a3$.

I'm just trying to work my way up using easier examples (and failing).

Any help is really appreciated!!

**edit
the first example has values of

$a= 1, b=.2, c=.04, d=.5$

and the initial conditions are

$x=10, y=2$

Comment: I should also mention, that I need it to be a square matrix as I am looking for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I am comfortable in how to get them, it's just getting the matrix that is puzzling me.

Comment: I've just realised I might have figured it out. Is it possible that \begin{equation*} a_{12} = \text{ is only the output of the first equation with no y,}\end{equation*}and \begin{equation*} a_{21} = \text{is only the input  part of the second equation with no y,}\end{equation*}?

I'm really just trying to find the pattern so I can try and solve my own examples.... Sorry for the edits and comments.